# Is it possible to have multiple GETs that vary only by parameters in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-routing

I want to build truly RESTful web service so don't want to leverage RPC-style, so have currently this:

```
[HttpGet]
[ActionName(nameof(GetByParticipant))]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetByParticipant([FromQuery]string participantId, [FromQuery]string participantType, [FromQuery]string programName)
{
}

[HttpGet]
[ActionName(nameof(GetByProgram))]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetByProgram([FromQuery]string programName)
{
}
```

And I believe that would work in ASP.NET Web API. But I'm getting an exception:

> AmbiguousActionException: Multiple actions matched. The following actions matched route data and had all constraints satisfied:
>
> TermsController.GetByParticipant (ParticipantTerms.Api)
>
> TermsController.GetByProgram (ParticipantTerms.Api)

Neither of the attributes actually help:

- `[HttpGet]`
- `[ActionName]`
- `[FromQuery]`

Comment: When using from query you need to uniquely differentiate the actions' routes otherwise you will get the ambiguous action exception. Reason being `api/action?participantId=1&participantType=2` is the same as `api/action?programName=x`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When using from query you need to uniquely differentiate the actions' routes otherwise you will get the ambiguous action exception. Reason being `api/action?participantId=1&participantType=2` is the same as `api/action?programName=x`

Suggestion:

```
public class ParticipantQuery {
    public string participantId { get; set; } 
    public string participantType { get; set; }
    public string programName { get; set; }
}

[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class TermsController : Controller {

    [HttpGet("participants")]  //GET api/terms/participants?participantId=123&....
    [ActionName(nameof(GetByParticipant))]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetByParticipant([FromQuery]ParticipantQuery model) {
        //...
    }

    [HttpGet("programs/{programName}")]//GET api/terms/programs/name
    [ActionName(nameof(GetByProgram))]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetByProgram(string programName) {
        //...
    }
}
```

Or you can use one action that encapsulates the available parameters and branch the result based on the provided members

```
public class GetTermsQuery {
    public string participantId { get; set; } 
    public string participantType { get; set; }
    public string programName { get; set; }
}

[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class TermsController : Controller {    
    [HttpGet]  //GET api/terms?participantId=123&....
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get([FromQuery]GetTermsQuery model) {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, to differentiate actions is the usual suggestion from what I could find here on SO. But I feel that wouldn't be proper REST which is resource-based, e.g. `GET api/terms/?cond=a` and `GET api/terms?cond=b` where `api/terms` is the terms resource.

Comment: Wondering whether there is a way to customize ASP.NET Core to mimic prior Web API's behavior

Comment: @abatishchev what are your thoughts in the provided update.

Comment: @abatishchev the catch is that both action make use of the common `programName`., otherwise you could have tried the `[FromRoute]` attribute.

Comment: Renaming programName to something else didn't help, unfortunately. I feel this is intentional design/limitation of ASP.NET Core. Looking for a way to customize this behavior.

Comment: Asked this question on [GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/6898) as well

Answer (score 21):

You can do this using an IActionConstraint.

Here is an example:

```
public class ExactQueryParamAttribute : Attribute, IActionConstraint
{
    private readonly string[] keys;

    public ExactQueryParamAttribute(params string[] keys)
    {
        this.keys = keys;
    }

    public int Order => 0;

    public bool Accept(ActionConstraintContext context)
    {
        var query = context.RouteContext.HttpContext.Request.Query;
        return query.Count == keys.Length && keys.All(key => query.ContainsKey(key));
    }
}

[HttpGet]
[ActionName(nameof(GetByParticipant))]
[ExactQueryParam("participantId", "participantType", "programName")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetByParticipant([FromQuery]string participantId, [FromQuery]string participantType, [FromQuery]string programName)
{
}

[HttpGet]
[ActionName(nameof(GetByProgram))]
[ExactQueryParam("programName")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetByProgram([FromQuery]string programName)
{
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've spent all day trying to do this and Andrew Radford's solution and this was perfect!

```
[HttpGet]
[ExactQueryParam("active")]
public IEnumerable<UserSelectAllSprocResult.DataRow> GetAll(
  [FromQuery] bool active)
{
  return ...
}

[HttpGet]
[ExactQueryParam("active", "companyId")]
public IEnumerable<UserSelectAllByCompanySprocResult.DataRow> GetByCompanyId(
  [FromQuery] bool active, [FromQuery] int companyId)
{
  return ...;
}
```