# AmbiguousActionException in same controller for different routes

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a controller getting AmbiguousActionException. I have 3 methods I want to perform
1.  Get a member based on their Id
2.  Find all members with certain eye color
3.  Get all members

The first works fine but 2 and 3 get AmbiguousActionException I assume because they both only use HTTPGet and nothing else.  Is there a way I can differentiate between a default HTTPGet with a query parameter and HTTPGet.  I'm using a query parameter as the eyecolor filter criteria, not a key for the member.

Here is my code:

```
namespace MyController.Controllers
{
    [Route("members")]
    public class MemberController: Controller
    {
        [HttpGet("{memberId}")]
        public IActionResult GetMemberFor(string memberId)
        {
            return Ok(DoSomeMethodWithId(memberId));
        }

        [HttpGet(Name = "FindMembersWith")]
        public IActionResult FindMembersFor([FromQuery(Name = "eyeColor")] string eyeColor)
        {
            return Ok(DoSomeOtherMethodWithFilter(eyeColor);
        } 

        [HttpGet(Name = "GetAllMembers")]
        public IActionResult GetAllMembers()
        {
            return Ok(DoMethodToRetrieveAllMembers);
        }
    }
}

urls:
www.mysite.com/members/{id} -- get single member by id
www.mysite.com/members  -- get all members
www.mysite.com/members?eyeColor=blue  --get all members with blue eyes
```

Is there something I can add to make the 2nd and 3rd routes work?

Answer (score 1):

You can add custom routes:

```
[Route("FindMembersWith")]
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult FindMembersFor([FromQuery(Name = "eyeColor")] string eyeColor)
{
   return Ok(DoSomeOtherMethodWithFilter(eyeColor);
} 

[Route("GetAllMembers")]
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetAllMembers()
{
    return Ok(DoMethodToRetrieveAllMembers);
}
```

Comment: I was hoping to have my url look like:www.mysite.com/members and www.mysite.com/members?eyeColor=blue.  is this not possible?

Comment: I actually found something that worked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46477959/is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-gets-that-vary-only-by-parameters-in-asp-net-cor

Comment: While this will work, it's not what the OP asked for. They're wanting to have the same route handle two different situations. Of course you can simply just use two different routes. That's not really ground-breaking information.