# How do I configure Model Binding with multiple controller methods of the same HTTP verb (and query parameters)?

Tags: asp.net-core

Well, I'm clearly doing something wrong here trying to get my REST API endpoints to route for these three use cases.
I get a **500** with the following:

```
The request matched multiple endpoints. Matches: 

Abc.FooBar.Controllers.FooController.GetByBar (Abc.FooBar)
Abc.FooBar.Controllers.FooController.Get (Abc.FooBar)
Abc.FooBar.Controllers.FooController.GetOnlyActive (Abc.FooBar)
```

I'm trying to allow the following functionality:

1. GET api/foo/  (returns all foo)
2. GET api/foo?onlyActive=false (returns all foo, even inactive ones)
3. GET api/foo?bar=123... (returns all foo whose bar equals 123...)

So I've tried this with two controller methods, and then this more verbose three, but it doesnt seem to be able to pick up my attributes for instructing it to match on these query parameters. Any ideas?

```cs
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class FooController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Foo>>> Get()
    {
        //
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Foo>>> GetOnlyActive([FromQuery(Name = "onlyActive")] bool onlyActive)
    {
        //
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Foo>>> GetByBar([FromQuery(Name = "bar")] Guid bar)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using a single method with optional parameters then applying your logic within it:

```
[HttpGet]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Foo>>> GetOnlyActive([FromQuery] bool onlyActive = false, [FromQuery] Guid? bar = null)
{
    //
}
```

Comment: Sure.  I had two of the three in one method originally.  Could add the 3rd, especially if I cant figure this out.  But.....as far as I can tell, with templates in the HttpGet attribute, Route attributes, and FromX attributes, I'm SUPPOSED to be able indicate which method I'd like MVC to route to for these use cases, no?

Comment: Query parameters don't generally define a route. If you want them to be part of the route you could use something like `[Route({onlyActive}]` and  `[Route({bar}]` and them access them with `api/Foo/true/` and `api/Foo/391171fe-ccaa-4474-947b-b78c0dc6344e`

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49033114/8532748 - it might do what you want.

Comment: It does, thanks! IActionConstraint. So, in summary, its actually not possible to natively route multiple actions against the same verb that vary only by query parameters.  Can route all your actions through one public controller method (as your example states), or use IActionConstraint and a bit of custom code to determine the behavior you want across multiple methods